# JS & Conditional Statement in 1 snippet

Tags: javascript, php

I am implementing code for our trusted e-commerce badge on 2 different languages of our website.

Thing is we have 2 languages ergo 2 "different" websites and IDs to go with them, the code is as follows and I want the var _tsid to change depending on what language the website is in.

I have a functioning PHP script but the issue is I can only this code on our CMS in a javascript box ergo the php script has no effect

Essentially I have 2 long 30digit codes that are our client IDs to represent our badge, so it needs to be interchangeable using only JS. Any help is greatly appreciated! I tried using a jsfiddle but with console.log etc to try and get a print or something was not functioning so I just stuck it here to hopefully see if someone can help me find a solution :)

**Functioning PHP Script + JS**

```
<?php 
if ($ts_lang == "en" || $ts_lang == "fr"){
      if ($ts_lang == "en"){ 
      $tsid = "Code1";
      }elseif($ts_lang == "fr"){
      $tsid = "Code2";
      }?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          (function () { 
          var _tsid = '<?php echo $tsid ;?>'; 
          _tsConfig = { 
              'yOffset': '0', //offset from page bottom
              'variant': 'reviews' //text, default, small, reviews
          };
          var _ts = document.createElement('script');
          _ts.type = 'text/javascript'; 
          _ts.async = true; 
          _ts.charset = 'utf-8'; 
          _ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js'; 
          var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
          })();
      </script>
<?php } ?>
```

**My attempt at JS if/else statement**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

    var sitelang = en;
    var _tsid;
    if (sitelang == en) {
      _tsid = "Code1";
    } else {
      _tsid = "Code2";
    }

(function() {
    _tsConfig = {
      'yOffset': '0', /* offset from page bottom */
      'variant': 'reviews', /* text, default, small, reviews, custom, custom_reviews */
      'customElementId': '', /* required for variants custom and custom_reviews */
      'trustcardDirection': '', /* for custom variants: topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft */
      'customBadgeWidth': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'customBadgeHeight': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'disableResponsive': 'false', /* deactivate responsive behaviour */
      'disableTrustbadge': 'false', /* deactivate trustbadge */
      'trustCardTrigger': 'mouseenter' /* set to 'click' if you want the trustcard to be opened on click instead */
    };
    var _ts = document.createElement('script');
    _ts.type = 'text/javascript';
    _ts.charset = 'utf-8';
    _ts.async = true;
    _ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js';
    var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
  })(); 

</script>
```

**This is the current functioning code that you can see the Trusted Shops badge on the bottom right of www.showstyle.lu**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () { 
    var _tsid = 'Code1'; 
    _tsConfig = { 
      'yOffset': '0', /* offset from page bottom */
      'variant': 'reviews', /* text, default, small, reviews, custom, custom_reviews */
      'customElementId': '', /* required for variants custom and custom_reviews */
      'trustcardDirection': '', /* for custom variants: topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, 

bottomLeft */
      'customBadgeWidth': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'customBadgeHeight': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'disableResponsive': 'false', /* deactivate responsive behaviour */
      'disableTrustbadge': 'false', /* deactivate trustbadge */
      'trustCardTrigger': 'mouseenter' /* set to 'click' if you want the trustcard to be opened on click instead */
    };
    var _ts = document.createElement('script');
    _ts.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    _ts.charset = 'utf-8'; 
    _ts.async = true; 
    _ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js'; 
    var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood but I think you need detect if sitelang is either "en" or "fr", so you can use `document.location.pathname` since you have http://www.showstyle.lu/en/ and http://www.showstyle.lu/fr/.

Try:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    var sitelang=document.location.pathname;
    //var sitelang = en;
    var _tsid;
    if (sitelang == "/en/") {
      _tsid = "Code1";
    } else {//"/fr/"
      _tsid = "Code2";
    }

(function() {
    _tsConfig = {
      'yOffset': '0', /* offset from page bottom */
      'variant': 'reviews', /* text, default, small, reviews, custom, custom_reviews */
      'customElementId': '', /* required for variants custom and custom_reviews */
      'trustcardDirection': '', /* for custom variants: topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft */
      'customBadgeWidth': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'customBadgeHeight': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'disableResponsive': 'false', /* deactivate responsive behaviour */
      'disableTrustbadge': 'false', /* deactivate trustbadge */
      'trustCardTrigger': 'mouseenter' /* set to 'click' if you want the trustcard to be opened on click instead */
    };
    var _ts = document.createElement('script');
    _ts.type = 'text/javascript';
    _ts.charset = 'utf-8';
    _ts.async = true;
    _ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js';
    var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
  })(); 

</script>
```

Comment: better use `sitelang.match(/^\/en\//)` since path can contain more stuff.

Comment: @jcubic It's true! It's hard to believe that website has only 2 URLs

Comment: Interesting, I'll test it for now I find an alternative solution using the websites if/endif tags and moved the JS to the bottom of the core pages instead of having it seperate `{% if shop.language == 'en' %}
    var _tsid = 'code1'; 
    {% endif %}  
   {% if shop.language == 'fr' %}
    var _tsid = 'code2';  
    {% endif %}`